# Save two references in one MySql field

Tags: mysql

I need to save in **one MySql field** two numeric values, **a** and **b**.
Both are natural numbers with a maximum of 11 characters, and they are going to be used in the next SQL structure.

```
"SELECT FROM table WHERE field=a and foild=b"
```

I thought about the next two possibilities:

1. Create a *DECIMAL* with {11},{11} range.
2. Create a *VARCHAR* with 23 chars and save them as "a.b" string.

Which is the best option? Is there any better option to get it work fast?

When saying fast I mean also the "cheapest" way to get **a** and **b** work in my query. Both examples would need a split process before using them, and I do not know if there is any way of doing this directly in one Query, having **a** and **b** as *curiousfield.part1* and *curiousfield.part2*...

Thanks, *(excuse me if **curiousfield** was too fantastic)*

**EDIT:**

Why do I want to store multiple values in One column?

Because I have the next **tables**:

**int-value**
*content [INT]*

**varchar-value**
*content [VARCHAR (100)]*

**text-value**
*content [TEXT]*

**magic-value**
*content [????]*

It is always being saved in "content" for many reasons, and making "magic-value" table to have content-a and content-b fields, would not be a nice solution in the requirements I am working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, no, no!

Don't ever store multiple values in one column. Period.

Comment: I updated my question, so I explain why I need to save multiple values in one column.

Comment: I read the update. My answer is still NO and always will be. Improve your DB structure  but don't violate the 1st rule in DB design. Never!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot save two decimal values in a column and which the data type of the column is `decimal`, it is better store it as two columns with data type of `decimal` than a column which values are separated by a comma.

It is much easy to search with using two numeric columns than a column with comma separated value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store nature number in DB than store in decimal or integer.
If you store as integer

1. Retrieval is easy.
2. you can do manipulation or calculation on them in sql itself.

If you store in a single field, the above benefit you cant get and more over you need to split /concatenation it whenever you are saving or retrieving from db.